# Оперативная память в игре (Dota 2)

Tags: windows, ram

У меня у процессора базовая частота 2,1 и турбо буст до 3,9. В игре, которая требует минимум 4гб оперативной памяти (дота 2). Если я ставлю настройки выше минимума, то турбо буст отключается и частота становится равной 2,1. Соответственно начинаются неприятное слайдшоу, перепады кадров. Но на минимальных всё в порядке. Всего у меня 8гб озу, операционка занимает 4 гб (Windows 11). То есть скорее всего дота забивает оставшиеся 4 гб (меньше, так как ноутбук и интегрированная подъедает немного), а если поднять качество текстур, то начинается нехватка памяти (моя догадка). Процессор intel core i3 8145u, Видеокарта nvidia geforce mx230 (2гб). Ноутбук вчера чистил от пыли и менял термопасту, винду тоже вчера переустановил и форматировал оба два диска (ссд под систему на 256 гб и 1тб жд дополнительный). Делал стресс тест в аиде, процессор не троттлил (тест около 10 мин гонял, может быть малвоато) Ноутбук не перегревается ( проц около 60-70 градусов).
Поможет ли в моём случае добавление 8 гб оперативной памяти? Чтобы процессор мог выкладываться на полную с турбо бустом?

Answer (score 0):

Начнем с того что объем оперативной памяти (далее - оперативка) в требованиях к игре указан с учетом потребления системой. То есть, в нашем случае игра будет потреблять 2-3 гигабайта от оставшегося объема. Но это еще указаны минимальные требования.

> **Цитата**
>
> Если я ставлю настройки выше минимума, то турбо буст отключается и частота становится равной 2,1.
>
> Делал стресс тест в аиде, процессор не тротлил (тест около 10 мин гонял, может быть маловато) Ноутбук не перегревается ( проц около 60-70 градусов).

Странно на самом деле. Мне лично кажется, что проблема заключается в перегреве. Попробуйте поиграть с RivaTuner. Он устанавливается в комплекте с MSI Afterburner, отдельно, как я знаю, установить нельзя. Настройте чтобы он показывал счетчики температур. И поиграйте так минут 10-20 и посмотрите на результат. Если температура поднималась, а потом резко опускалась, скорее всего это тротлинг.

> **Цитата**
>
> Поможет ли в моём случае добавление 8 гб оперативной памяти?

Это поможет только в том случае если игра использует весь оставшийся объем оперативки, то есть забивает его под полную. Процессору это вряд-ли поможет.

Честно скажу вам, я не эксперт. Это лишь мои предположения и догадки. Если есть еще информация напишите под этим ответом комментарий. Ситуация очень странная :/ .

Comment: добавление оперативки также лечит тормоза жесткого диска